# How to avoid the ribbon groups to be changed by a dropdown button

Tags: excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

I have this ribbon defined in my VSTO addin for Excel:

[image]

When I run the application in a narrow monitor, the ribbon appears like this:

[image]

How to avoid the groups to be changed by a drop down button? If I decrease window width, default ribbon groups are not changed, only my custom groups, so I am pretty sure it is possible.

I have read something about "autoScale" property in XML, but I am not sure how to apply that in my case.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Maybe its just me, but I don't understand the problem. Maybe you could be a little more clear about what the issue is.

Comment: @STHOH Please see the right most buttons in the ribbon, for example, the one that reads "Cédula de Identidad". That dropdown button was placed automatically by Excel because the application window does not allow the group to fit. If I maximize the window, That button is replaced by the actual ribbon group. Other example. If I decrease application window width, the group "Lectura de cedulas de identidad" is replaced by that ugly drop down button. If that is a behaviour of Excel and cannot be changed, how can I change that ugly button icon?

Comment: I don't know of a way to avoid Excel collapsing the group when there isn't enough screen space. You can set a icon for the group using either the 'image' attribute or det 'getImage' attribute on the directly on the ribbong group. When the group is collapsed to a dropdown, this will be the image that is shown.